# Как сделать это в css?

Tags: html, css

[image: img]

Ребята, как сделать эту загогулинку в css ?) я так понимаю это кусочек зигзага.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573175/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать два треугольника — один снизу, чуть большего размера, другой сверху, чуть меньшего.

```css
.elm {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

    .elm:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      left: 10px;
      top: -1px;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
      border-color: #ccc transparent transparent transparent;
    }

    .elm:after {
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      left: 11px;
      top: -1px;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 9px 9px 0 9px;
      border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
    }
```

```html
<div class="elm"></div>
```